# How to debug across Swift Modules?

Tags: ios, swift, debugging, module, architecture

**How to continue debugging across Swift Modules using breakpoints?**

While working in `Swift` project, I have one large app which I want to refactor into two projects (`modules`) for better modularity, modifiability and maintainability. However, I am concern about the way of `debuggability`. When the code is in single project, developers can debug with breakpoints until the line of the root cause but after refactoring into two separate projects, how do developers debug if the entry breakpoint starts in one project and ends in other? Is there any way to continue across the projects to debug and issue? Or is this a common problem for modular applications?

For example let's say, I have separated single app called `MyApp` into below two modules,

1. `App` - Hosting main project
2. `Feature` - Framework project

#### Module: App, Class: AppInterfaceLayer

```
import Foundation
import Feature

class AppInterfaceLayer {

    public func printMe(printString: String){
        FrameworkServiceLayer().printMe(printString: printString) // entry point of debugging
    }
}
```

#### Module: Feature, Class: FrameworkServiceLayer

```
import Foundation

public class FrameworkServiceLayer {

    public init(){}
    public func printMe(printString: String) {
        // an error is produced here
    }
}
```

How to deal with this problem?

---

<sup>**Note:** I have tried to show a minimal workable example with above codes. In actual project the communications will be too much tangled.</sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you're importing the Xcode project, or multiple projects, into a workspace, breakpoints will continue to work as expected. Cocoapods work this way for example.

If you intend to use binary frameworks, then not so much, but that does not seem to be the case for you.

Comment: Will it also include the unsymbolicated stack traces for crashes in Fabric by default?

Comment: This doesn't work if you're working on a swift package, even if it's a local package. When Stepping into code, it just skips right over the code for the package.